# AsParameters in Minimal Apis does not load nested objects from the querystring

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-8.0, minimal-apis

I'm using **Minimal Apis** together with **MediatR** and I'm having a problem passing parameters via **querystring**, below the querystring:

```
/api/Relogio?Name=&ProductRef.Code=asdsadsadsadsadasdsasadsa&ProductRef.Year=12&CurrentPage=1&PageSize=15
```

The simple properties like `Name` are being filled, but the complex `ProductRef.Code` and `ProductRef.Year` are not being filled

Below the request class

```
public class GetAllProductsRequest : IRequest<PaginatedList<GetProductResponse>>
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public ProductRef? ProductRef { get; set; } // This Object not loaded
    public int CurrentPage { get; set; } = 1;
    public int PageSize { get; set; } = 15;
}
```

The `ProductRef` class not being populated

```
public class ProductRef
{
    public string Code { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int? Year { get; set; }
}
```

"Action" from Minimal Api, uses the `AsParameters` attribute

```
group.MapGet("/", async (IMediator mediator, [AsParameters] GetAllProductsRequest request) =>
{
    var result = await mediator.Send(request);
    return result;
});
```

Why are nested complex properties not being populated?

Version used: `.NET 8.0.2 x64`

Comment: Just to be sure - the problematic endpoint is GET, not POST/PUT/PATCH?

Answer (score 1):

From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#parameter-binding-for-argument-lists-with-asparameters):

> `AsParametersAttribute` enables simple parameter binding to types and not complex or recursive model binding.

I assume this case falls under "complex" one.

TBH for me it does not only "skips" filling the `ProductRef` but produces exception on app startup (since `ProductRef` is inferred as body parameter by default):

> InvalidOperationException: Body was inferred but the method does not allow inferred body parameters.

The workaround would be custom binding with [`BindAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis/parameter-binding?view=aspnetcore-8.0#bindasync). Something to get you started:

```cs
public class ProductRef
{
    // ...

    public static ValueTask<ProductRef> BindAsync(HttpContext context,
        ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        var productRef = new ProductRef
        {
            Code = context.Request.Query[$"{parameter.Name}.Code"],
            // ....
        };
        return ValueTask.FromResult(productRef);
    }
}
```